# How to calculate and determine the density function of the sum of a random sample of 25?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I am preparing a test and I'm stuck at this question.

If the mean and standard deviation of the population are known (normally distributed), how should I calculate the sum of a random sample of 25?

I have to determine its density function and probabily when the sum is less or more than a certain value.

Thank you!

Comment: Sum is normal with mean times 25 and 25 squared times the variance.

Comment: @jdods You confuse sum $X_1+\ldots+X_{25}$ and $25X_1$.

Comment: The question was " mean =250" "variance=40", write down the probability density function of T, which is the sum of a random sample of 25 and compute the probability that T is less than 6400. Could you explain how to get the density function and probability?

Comment: If the $X_n$, for $n=1,2,...,25$, are independent and normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{25} X_n$ is normal with mean $25\mu$ and variance $25^2\sigma^2$.

Comment: @jdods Your response is incorrect, as NCh correctly identified.

Comment: Oops! That's embarrassing!

Answer (score 2):

The following fact is generally useful and worth knowing: if $X_1 \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $X_2 \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ are independent, then $X_1 + X_2 \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_1 + \mu_2, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)$. The cleanest proofs of this rely on either a moment generating function or a characteristic function, typically, but this can also be shown directly.

By applying this result several times to your sample, you can see that the sum is normally distributed with mean $25 \mu$ and variance $25 \sigma^2$. As soon as you know this, you can immediately write down the density function or the distribution function of the variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer So, when calculating for the probability that T is less than 6400, should I do this : Z=(6400-25μ) / 5σ ? or Z=(6400-25μ) / σ ?

Comment: Assuming T refers to the total, the first thing you suggested is right.

Comment: That really helped me so much. Thanks~!